# Why do I need to create an instance of the class I am working in?

Tags: java, class, oop

OK I am learning OOP at the moment, and there are a few things I don't understand. For example I have a class called PersonProgram that contains my main. I have several methods and functions outside of my main method within the class. Why can I not call those methods and functions from the main without creating a new object of the class? Since they are all in the same class, why doesn't it make sense to just be able to call them like any other method, without
    PersonProgram p = new PersonProgram();
first?

Comment: Well if they're instance methods, they have to operate on an instance. The `main` method is static - it *isn't* operating on an instance. Either your methods don't depend on instance state, in which case they should *possibly* be static, or they do, in which case it certainly makes sense to create an instance.

Comment: It doesn't make sense without creating the Object first because that is how OOP works

Comment: This was also my very first question when I started to learn Java: why in the world do I need a class to print "Hello, World!"? Glad to know I'm not the only one who's wondering.

Comment: @GOTO0 For that the answer is rather more simple: you have to start somewhere. You might as well start in a class. :) Joking aside, after having spent a bit of time working in Java you soon realise that the `main()` method is really nothing special, it's just a fairly arbitrary way to get the ball rolling.

Comment: @biziclop By that logic, you are already IN an instance of a class, so you should be able to use all variables and methods in that class.

Comment: @ajspacemanspiff Which instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can I not call those methods and functions from the main without creating a new object of the class?

Because they are not `static`

You have to create an instance to be able to use them. Add the modifier, so you can have access to them. For instance,

```
private static getSomething()
```

And then, call it from main as:

```
getSomething()
```

*Also pay attention to what the almighty @JonSkeet said in the comments.*

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: Because the main method is *static*, meaning that it belongs to the class and not a particular object. Static contexts cannot reference non-static context because there is no reference of a particular object in mind.

But you could just make all of your other variables and methods `static` too, and there, problem solved, right?

No. Don't do that.

The long answer:

The main method is `static` because none of your application's custom defined objects exist before its started. After all, you can't have something exist in a room before the room exists. The JVM needs an entry point to your program, however, so the main method must be free of all object references, hence `static`.

Java calls `PersonProgram.main(args)` just as your application starts. Now let's say you have defined what a "Person" is in your `PersonProgram` class. Maybe a `PersonProgram` has a name, an age, etc. But you don't have any `PersonProgram` objects yet, so how does the `main` method know what name or age it's supposed to be working with?

Here's a way to make things clearer for you: Make a new class called `Application` and put only your main method in it. Now, try to refer to your `PersonProgram`'s instance variables. You won't be able to do it unless you create a `PersonProgram` object first.

You've just started learning OOP concepts, and the idea of putting the `main` method in your class definitions can become confusing. It makes it easier to learn to code, but you should try keeping your `main` method separate from your class logic as you try to learn OOP principles.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially because you could have multiple instances of the same class.

```
Dog bigDog = new Dog();
Dog littleDog = new Dog();
```

Now what if you wanted to know the name of your dog?
`Dog.GetName();`, right? Which dog's name would that return? You have to tell that to the compiler by calling the function on an instance of the class.

```
bigDog.GetName();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle more than 2 persons in your product then you can do with,

```
PersonProgram p1 = new PersonProgram();// Have p1.name="First person"
PersonProgram p2 = new PersonProgram();// Have p2.name="Second person"
```

so on ...

If you know there is only one person then you can create static class and you wont need to create new object and use directly without creating instance.

so OOP gives you both option, select one which suites you.

Answer (score 0):

Understand that the driving force behind the creation of `Object Oriented Programming` is to couple memory/data with the operations that can be run on it. So in OOP, Objects are intended most of the time to provide services on the data that they contain, whereas static methods are fundamentally for stateless processes.

Answer (score 0):

Basic OOP rule:

A class makes all its non-private, non-static members available only through its instantiated object.

This applies even when the members are requested from the same class. Although you can access private members of your class as well.

To use `this.method()`, you will have to make the method static.